# sub expression and grouping of subexpressins

Tags: c

I'm new to c language. Did "precedence" determine the grouping of sub expression.  
 Can you explain how sub grouping works?

Explain why the strange output come when I do `i=7; ++i+++i+++i;` shows error while just putting space between `++i + ++i + ++i;` don't give any error and answer is 22 in Gcc; how this output come?

I checked books also most of them have some "precedence" order and than some" associativity rules", no clear explanation about sub grouping. 
can you explain me what to do whenever I saw these kind of mix expression. Almost every c language aptitude ask such type of question.

Comment: It was hard to tell the difference between `i` which is you and `i` the variable :)

Comment: Try to understand what the error actually says. Then the answer should come to you. Also remember the "maximum munch" rule.

Comment: Never ming the result of `++i + ++i + ++i` in GCC. It is undefined behavior. Executing it will not tell you anything about order of evaluation or about precedence.

Comment: Also, undefined behaviour.

Comment: here i is the variable

Comment: what is the maximum munch rule

Comment: Any aptitude test can be passed with a 90% success rate by reading and understanding the http://c-faq.com/expr/index.html comp.lang.c FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

This is a duplicate of a few questions on SO, but here goes.

### Maximal Munch

The C parser will try to grab as many characters as it can to split your program into tokens. In `++i+++i+++i;` the parser splits the string into:

1. ++
2. i
3. ++
4. +
5. i
6. ++
7. +
8. i
9. ;

It then sees that preincrement (token 1) and postincrement (token 3) are both applied to the first `i` (token 2), and reports an error.  The parser does not backtrack and reparse the string to use `+` for token 3 and `++` for token 4. If the compiler had the license to do this, a malicious program could take arbitrarily-long time to parse.

### Multiple Side-Effects

`C` and its family of languages defines a *sequence point* as a point in a statement's execution where all variables have definite values. It is undefined behavior to have more than one side-effect  occur to a variable between sequence points.  Simplify your example a bit. What could this code do? I have changed a preincrement to a predecrement so I can talk about them easier.

```
int j = ++i + --i;
```

1. Increment `i`.
2. Use the incremented value for the first summand.
3. Decrement `i`.
4. Use the decremented value for the second summand.
5. Add the two values and assign to `j`.

However, the C standard does not fix the order of these effects except that step 1 must precede step 2, step 3 must precede step 4, and step 5 must be last. What your compiler does  need not be what another compiler does, and it need not be consistent, even in the same program.  As the joke in the Jargon File goes:

> nasal demons, n.
>
> Recognized shorthand on the Usenet group comp.std.c for any unexpected behavior of a C
>   compiler on encountering an undefined construct. During a discussion on that group in early
>   1992, a regular remarked “When the compiler encounters [a given undefined construct] it is
>   legal for it to make demons fly out of your nose” (the implication is that the compiler may
>   choose any arbitrarily bizarre way to interpret the code without violating the ANSI C
>   standard). Someone else followed up with a reference to “nasal demons”, which quickly
>   became established. The original post is web-accessible at http://groups.google.com/groups?hl=en&selm=10195%40ksr.com.